# Jest not using my mocks but is for functions imported via node_modules

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I have a Jest test which is building a redux component, part of that component calls a number of sagas which in turn call a number of ajax functions.

One of these ajax functions is using the CoreApi component from https://github.com/kineticdata/react-kinetic-core another is in a local function.

I have mocked both these functions in /src/__mocks__ - the mocks for CoreApi are called. The mocks I have for my own function are not and the underlying functions are being called.

My test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {fireEvent, cleanup, waitForDomChange, wait} from '@testing-library/react'
import {renderWithRedux} from '../../../../helpers/testSetup'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
import {Container} from '../container'

// test setup
afterEach(cleanup)
beforeEach(() => {
 // fetch.resetMocks();
});

// consts
const match = {  
  params: {
    id: "123"
  }
} 

// tests
describe('Timeline Container', () =>  {

  it('Rendering timeline', async  () => {
      const {getAllByText,getByTestId,findByTestId,store} = renderWithRedux(<Container match={match} />)
      expect(getAllByText("Loading request")[0]).toBeVisible()

      // 2. Act

      // 3. Assert
  })

})
```

My mock for CoreApi (which is called from within the Container compoenents saga)

```
const CoreAPI = {}

function fetchSpace() {
  console.log("in space mock")
  return (
    {
      "space": {
        "attributes": [{"a":"b"}]
      }
    }
  )
}

CoreAPI.fetchSpace = fetchSpace

export { CoreAPI }
```

My mock for my local functions:

```
const getHeader = () => {
  console.log("in the mock  header")
  return(
    JSON.stringify({
      "request": {
        "title": "TEST"
      },
      "error": false,
      "errorLevel": 0
    })
  )
}

export const JspAccess = {
  getHeader
}
```

Where as my real function looks like:

```
const getHeader = (id) => {
  console.log("doing fetch call for "+id)
  return fetch("/api/?callback=lookup.json&id="+id",
    {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
  )
}

export const JspAccess = {
  getHeader
}
```

But my Jest output is showing the console.logs from the real function not the mock but is using the mock for my CoreApi calls:

```
 PASS  src/components/app/__tests__/Container.test.js
  ● Console

console.log src/lib/api/jspAccess.js:2
  doing fetch call for 123
console.log src/__mocks__/react-kinetic-core.js:8
  in space mock
```

I don't understand if my mocks are in the same place why one is picked up and the other not. Any ideas?!

Comment: `__mocks__` directory has to be on the same level in directory structure as the modules it has mocks for. So, for `src/foo.js` it has to be `src/__mocks__/foo.js`, for `src/utils/bar.js` it has to be `src/utils/__mocks__/bar.js`. Do you have the mocks in the right places?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've tried them in lots of places including the above but always ignored. Are there any other requirements other than being in the same place and providing the same functions?

Comment: so, I've found something that works which is putting this in my tests, which isn't great as it requires my tests to have knowledge about a sub components make up: `jest.mock('../../../../lib/api/jspAccess', () => jest.requireActual('../../../../lib/api/__mocks__/jspAccess'))` as mentioned on here https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/335

Comment: I'm not aware of any other requirements. That way indeed isn't great. I have no other ideas though.